# How to convert a function based data pipeline to OOP?

Tags: python, oop

I am doing some data processing and have built several pipelines, each consisting of multiple functions that broadly modify dictionaries at each step. As the different pipelines operate on the same data and have similar functions I've been trying to convert it into a more OOP orientated structure. However, before I get started I've been tying myself up in knots slightly.

Take the following simplified example:

```
for f in foos:
    y = extract_y_info(f)
    z = extract_z_info(f)
    *some code that does something with y and z*
    
def extract_y_info(f):
    return *some code that extracts y info from f*

def extract_z_info(f):
    return *some code that extracts z info from f*
```

To me there seems to be a couple of ways I could approach moving this to an OOP structure. The first is quite similar to the function by function approach.

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def extract_y_info(self):
        return *some code that extracts y info from self.x*

    def extract_z_info(self):
        return *some code that extracts z info from self.x*

for f in foo_instances:
    y = b.extract_y_info()
    z = b.extract_z_info()
    *some code that does something with y and z*
```

The other option is modifying the instances of the class:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def extract_y_info(self):
        self.y = *some code that extracts y info from self.x*

    def extract_z_info(self):
        self.z = *some code that extracts z info from self.x*

for f in foo_instances:
    f.extract_y_info()
    f.extract_z_info()
    *some code that does something with f.y and f.z*
```

Is either of these options better practice than the other? Is there a better third way?

Comment: Honestly I think you might have a better time with just free functions, unless you need inheritance (and nothing's preventing you from mixing and matching classes and functions in your pipeline)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your overall design is and what state do you expect your instances to be at any given time and what you do with it (in other words, is existence of `y` attribute itself meanigul, but... former seems generally safer to me. You call and you get a value, you don't have to keep track, have I called the method and what state is this or that attribute in? Note though, you should really define instance attributes in the constructor, otherwise the access could be not just surprising, but fatal (`AttributeError`).

Now a neat solution addressing some of the above point and possibly fitting to what you seem to be doing here to access the values could be a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), which essentially allows you to access value returned by a method as if it was a instance attribute:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def extract_y_info(self):
        return #some code that extracts y info from self.x

    y = property(extract_y_info)     

for f in foo_instances:
    print(f"value of f.y = {f.y}")
```

Or you can do the same using `property` as method decorator:

```
    @property
    def y(self):
        return #some code that extracts y info from self.x
```

If getting `y` was expensive and its value does not change across the life of instance, starting Python 3.8 you can also use [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property).

Comment: Thanks for this! One quick question... you wrote "you should really define instance attributes in the constructor" - does this mean that I should always define ```self.y``` and ```self.z``` in ```__init__()``` even if they are set to ```None``` to start with?

Comment: Yes. A good reason is: your instance interface (its attributes) is easy to understand by looking at the constructor and attributes set in constructor. The difference to what you asked then also being, if not assigned in constructor and accessed before a method that would do so, `f.z` would raise `AttributeError`, if you assigned `None` to it in the constructor (`__init__`) you would it would get `None` even it did not have any special value (but also for this I would still generally prefer: `return` over manipulate/access combo if getting value is what I want.